# JSF 2.0 @ManagedProperty is not been set

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am just starting using JSF and I don't understand why my service is not injected into my controller.

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyController {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{service}")
    private MyService service;

    public void setService(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public MyService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void callToService(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        System.out.println(service);
    }

}
```

**Q: What is the purpose of the value in the `@ManagedProperty`?**

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyService {

}
```

Clicking on the button calls the method `callToService` but the service is `null`.

```
<h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Call Service">
            <f:ajax listener="#{myController.callToService}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen when `#{service}` actually resolves to `null`.

When you use `@ManagedBean` without the `name` attribute as you did, the managed bean name will by default resolve to the classname with 1st char lowercased (at least, conform the Javabeans spec), so your `MyService` bean will effectively get a managed bean name of `myService`.

So there are basically 2 ways to fix this problem,

1. Use `#{myService}` instead.

   ```
   @ManagedProperty("#{myService}")
   private MyService service;
   ```
2. Specify the managed bean name yourself so that it becomes available as `#{service}`.

   ```
   @ManagedBean(name="service")
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class MyService {

   }
   ```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, since you don't seem to be interested in the ajax event, but rather in the action event, then you can also simplify the use of `<f:ajax>` as follows:

```
<h:commandButton value="Call Service" action="#{myController.callToService}">
    <f:ajax />
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
public void callToService() {
    System.out.println(service);
}
```

so that it'll still work when the enduser doesn't have JS enabled.

Finally, a business service is normally designed as a `@Stateless` EJB, not as a JSF managed bean since it should have no direct relationship with a JSF view. You could then just use

```
@EJB
private MyService service;
```

Comment: I followed your advise on using `@EJB` but it's not working. I guess I need to change the annotation of `MyService` since it's not a managed bean anymore.

Comment: Yes, use `@Stateless`. Note that you would need a servletcontainer which supports EJBs as well, such as Glassfish, JBoss, etc.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 6 but I added `openejb` in my classpath using maven. Just to make sure, `MyService` only needs the `@Stateless`? Because I get this exception: Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name com.xxxxxxxx.controller.MyController is not bound in this Context

Comment: Sorry, I have no hands-on experience with Tomcat+OpenEJB. The docs however state that it should work just fine: http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/tomcat.html